# All host(s) tried for query failed - com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException- Operation timed out)

Tags: java, cassandra, timeout, datastax-enterprise

We have set up a 3 node cassandra cluster on Digital Ocean and have written some java program which uses the Java CQL driver to connect to the cassandra. The queries continue to run for a while, but after some time we are getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /128.199.98.201:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/128.199.98.201] Operation timed out))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1402)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:164)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:343)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:316)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:254)
at com.attinad.cantiz.iot.platform.cassandrasample.PagingExample.connect(PagingExample.java:24)
at com.attinad.cantiz.iot.platform.cassandrasample.App.main(App.java:31)
```

The various time out values in the cassandra.yaml is given below

1. range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
2. write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
3. counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
4. cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
5. truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
6. request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

Any idea whether the issue is time out related or is a coding problem... Any help is appreciated